# What is a good browser for web application pen testing?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, penetration-test, xss

I am getting started in testing web applications, and I am having trouble verifying vulnerabilities.

It seems all modern browsers have protections against things like XSS.

When something like Burp finds an XSS vulnerability, I can't ever verify it when using something like TamperData. The code gets sent to the page, but it never seems to execute.

Is there a browser that specifically allows things like XSS and CSRF to execute, for the purposes of testing?

Comment: There is [PenQ](http://www.qburst.com/products/PenQ) from QBurst. It is open source and free to download.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most browsers allow you to disable the function. For instance with chrome you need to start the browser using

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --args --disable-web-security`

For Firefox you have to go type `about:config` in the address bar. Then you need to set the `browser.urlbar.filter.javascript` to False.

For Internet Explorer click Tools–>Internet Options and then navigate to the Security Tab. You need to set a custom security level. Scroll towards the bottom where you will find that Enable XSS filter and disable it.

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet would be mantra from OWASP:

http://www.getmantra.com/

Contains a myriad of tools for penetration testing out of the box. Also open source should you need to add/modify anything.

Answer (score 5):

> When something like Burp finds an XSS vulnerability, I can't ever verify it when using something like TamperData.

If you are already using Burp to find the vulnerability, why not use the [intercepting proxy functionality](http://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_intercept.html) to modify the request and to inject the XSS payload?

[image: Burp Intercepting Proxy]

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying, and what was failing.

Comment: Sonny: Maybe it was a false positive in this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Sandcat project](http://www.syhunt.com/sandcat/index.php) which provide a lot of pen testing tools, like scripting in lua, better view over the console and dynamic injection tools, and a lot of other good surprises.

Some of its unique features include:

- Live HTTP Headers — built-in live headers with a dedicated cache per tab and support for preview extensions
- Sandcat Console — an extensible command line console; Allows you to easily run custom commands and scripts in a loaded page
- Resources tab — allows you to view the page resources, such as JavaScript files and other web files.
- Page Menu extensions — allows you to view details about a page and more.
- Pen-Tester Tools — Sandcat comes with a multitude of pen-test oriented extensions. This includes a Fuzzer, a Script Runner, HTTP & XHR Editors, Request Loader, Request Replay capabilities

#### Screenshot

[image: ss1]